# How can I use and authorize an http proxy with node.js http.Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, proxy

I'm sending an http request over a proxy an need to add username and password to my request. How do I correctly add these values to my options block?

This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  port: 8080,
  host: 'my.proxy.net',
  path: '/index',
  headers: {
   Host: "http://example.com"
  }
};


http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("StatusCode: " + res.statusCode + " Message: " + res.statusMessage);
});
```

Currently the response is **StatusCode: 307, Message: Authentication Required**.

I tried to add username and password to my options but it doesn't work:

```
var options = {
    port: 8080,
    host: 'my.proxy.net',
    username: 'myusername',
    password: 'mypassword',
    path: '/index',
    headers: {
       Host: "http://example.com"
    }
};
```

**Additional Info:**
I don't have much information about the proxy, but in another case this authentication method worked:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@my.proxy.net:8080
```

Comment: It really depends on the type of proxy you are going through and the type of authentication scheme it supports, do you have more information about the proxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this works with my local squid:

```
var http = require('http');

function buildAuthHeader(user, pass) {
    return 'Basic ' + new Buffer(user + ':' + pass).toString('base64');
}

proxy = 'localhost';
proxy_port = 3128;
host = 'www.example.com';
url = 'http://www.example.com/index.html';
user = 'potato';
pass = 'potato';

var options = {
    port: proxy_port,
    host: proxy,
    path: url,
    headers: {
        Host: host,
       'Proxy-Authorization': buildAuthHeader(user, pass),
    }
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("StatusCode: " + res.statusCode + " Message: " + res.statusMessage);
});
```

Couple notes:

1. The full URL must be included in the GET line, not just the path, so its not /index.html but http://example.com/index.html
2. You should also include the host in the host header, so you will have to parse the URL properly

Comment: It is working without the host in the header. Why do I need it?

Comment: Well in principle its mandatory, but if it works without, it's a free world!:)

Comment: Honestly, if I were you, I'd include it. But that depends on the proxy and it's implementation...

Comment: It seems the server isn't reacting to the Host parameter. It's working even if I just write "foo" instead of the correct host...

Comment: Well maybe they just ignore it. Its implementation-dependent. As I said, in theory, that's mandatory, and the proxy has to check it, but maybe the guys who wrote it decided to ignore the host header and use the URL instead. Which kind of makes sense because it's redundant, but that's the standard... For example, Firefox the browser includes both, the full URL and the host header, when talking to a proxy.

Comment: This was the only one I found that worked for me. Cheers!